# Ruby on Rails session[:counter ] increases by two

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I am studying pragmatic bookshelf lessons. I try to make a session counter. 
my  store controller is

```
  class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def increment_counter
  if session[:counter].nil?
    session[:counter] = 0
  end
  session[:counter] += 1
end
  def index
    @count = increment_counter
    @products  = Product.all
    @cart = current_cart
    @time = Time.now
    @shown_message = "You've been here #{@count} times" if increment_counter >5
  end
end
```

and my view is

```
<h5><p><%= @shown_message %></p></h5>..
```

until 5 times it does not work . but after it starts to count as 5,7,9,11. . what is wrong with my session[:counter]?

Answer (score 8):

You call `increment_counter` twice in your action : first when setting @count, and then again in your condition for @shown_message.

Answer (score 3):

In complement to ksol answer. Use @count in the last call.

```
def index
  @count = increment_counter
  @products  = Product.all
  @cart = current_cart
  @time = Time.now
  @shown_message = "You've been here #{@count} times" if @count >5
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your store_controller.rb better code like that:

```
before_action :session_counter

def session_counter
  if session[:counter].nil?
    session[:counter] = 0
  end

  session[:counter] += 1
  @session_counter = session[:counter]
end
```

In store.html.erb like that:

```
<p>
  <% if @counter>5 %>
    <%= "U have visit the store #{@session_counter}  times!" %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

looks a pretty nice and works easy.

Comment: Good that you provided working solution. 
But your answer does not say WHY session counter gives "wrong" result.
It's good to give an explanation of the problem, not just solve it.

Comment: Yes, you right. I think about this in future. I'm new in programming... )