# Rails 4 session is not updated between requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, session, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say we have a very simple controller's show action:

```
def show
  session[:shown_counter] ||= 0
  session[:shown_counter] += 1
  puts "session id: #{session.id}"
  puts "shown #{session[:shown_counter]} times"
end
```

When I hit the url that invokes this action from my browser(chrome), it works as expected and I see the `shown_counter` increment. But I have a flash that makes some (5-10) requests to the correct URL, invokes my show action, but I can see that the counter is not increased although the session id is always the same.

When I reload the flash, I'll see that the counter increased by 1, but get "stuck" until I refresh the flash again or I make a "regular" request (with the browser).

How does it work? Why the counter doesn't grow with the flash requests?

Comment: how flash is working ? can you explain it . also have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016509/ruby-on-rails-sessioncounter-increases-by-two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to the flash creator, I think I got an answer.

The requests are asynchronous, that means a request won't wait for a response => the cookie won't be updated => the session (that uses the cookie store) won't be updated as well.

I guess this is the scenario, please tell if it makes sense to you and if you agree / disagree.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your Flash app needs to get the session cookie as provided by your Rails app server in a `Set-Cookie` header, store the data provided, and pass this key-value pair as a `Cookie` header on its next request.

(Save the `_myapp_session=Xyz(etc.)` part from each response, in other words, and pass it as `Cookie` on each subsequent request.)

Otherwise, Rails won't know to which session your request belongs.

Comment: I don't think it's the case, because I get the SAME session ID for each flash request (as I stated in my original question) - means Rails knows exactly which session the requests belong.